# Android: How to disable reverse slide animation to startDestination

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm working on simple application with three Fragments. I navigate between the fragments via simple three items menu.

For amination I use two Transactions that implement the sliding in and out effects. When I select different fragments from menu the transaction animation works just fine: slides from right to left. Except the navigation to first fragment. For it animation executes reverse slide: from left to right. Fragment 1 selected as *startDestinatoion* in navigation file, so it showed up first.

Is it possible somehow to disable that reverse sliding to the fragment marked as *startDestinatoion*? Or I have to use different implementations of animation?

I've added Transitions to onCreate() methods in each Fragment code:

*1/2/3Fragment.kt*

```js
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val inflater = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext())
    enterTransition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_right)
    exitTransition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_left)
  }
```

Animation files:

*slide_left.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<slide xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:slideEdge="left" />
```

*slide_right.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<slide xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:slideEdge="right" />
```

Navigation file is very simple.

*nav.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_1"
        android:name="com.example.ui.View1Fragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_2"
        android:name="com.example.ui.View2Fragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_3"
        android:name="com.example.ui.View3Fragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_3"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_3"/>
</navigation>
```